# shorter way to join 2 columns with the same name SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, join, mariadb

I am working with SQL again and recall there being a way to join 2 columns with the same name without mentioning both, the syntax was something like this: `LEFT JOIN ON(colname)` as opposed to `LEFT JOIN ON(a.colname = b.colname)` does anyone know the command I'm looking for?

I tried `ON(colname)` but this didn't work.

Comment: You can use `USING`, e.g. `FROM Table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 USING (colname)` - https://dbfiddle.uk/unbSOI73

Comment: Note that the result will only contain one colname column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to mention the column only once, but that's not with the `ON` keyword, it's using the `USING` keyword. Like so:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2
USING (columnName);
```